# Replacing first word in range causes omitting that from range in word office js

Tags: office-js, word-addins

I am working on project where I want to replace words in paragraph range.When I replace first word from the range it omits the first replaced word and starts from second word which causing position mismatch issue for me.
This is code snippet to reproduce it:

```
function run() {
  Word.run(async (context) => {
    console.log("script started");
    try{
    var para = context.document.body.paragraphs;
      context.load(para, 'text');
      await context.sync();
    var range = para.items[0].getRange();
      context.load(range, 'text');
      await context.sync();
      console.log(range.text); //here it shows whole paragraph

      var found = "learn"; //first words in paragraph
      var replacement = "Learn"; //replacements

      
        var searchResults = range.search(found,{matchCase: true , matchWholeWord:true});
        context.load(searchResults,'text');
        await context.sync();
        searchResults.items[0].insertText(replacement,Word.InsertLocation.replace);

      context.load(range,'text');
      await context.sync();
      console.log(range.text); //first replaced word is missing from range
    } catch (err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
}
```

Note : change the found and replacement to first word from your text.

Comment: I can reproduce this. Please create a bug in the [office-js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose).  In the meantime, a workaround is to get a new proxy object for the range by inserting this line just above the last context.load: `range = para.items[0].getRange();`.

Comment: Thanks @RickKirkham , This solution works for full paragraph,but for replacements only in paritial selection of paragraph with replacement at first word of selection I am using `range = range.appendTo(searchResults.items[0])`, whether it will be work well or is there any better solution.